# Would a participle phrase with an independent clause still form a simple sentence?

Tags: grammar

"Drinking his coffee, Stepan started reading through his letters."

Would a sentence structure like this one, with a participle clause joined to an independent clause, count as a simple sentence?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think I'd call it a 'simple sentence', but the clause "drinking his coffee" is not embedded as a dependent in a larger clause, so 'complex' is not appropriate either. This is where the terms 'simple', 'complex' etc. become meaningless. Forget them, they are neither use nor ornament.

Comment: It's also, more generally, where more realistic treatments of grammar part company with the simplified schemes taught in many schools. If you've got past the school/school exam stage, you can dig deeper, and realise that a lot of what is taught at school level is inadequate and sometimes inaccurate. If you're still at the former stage, learn how to pass the exams, but realise that you may later have to unlearn quite a bit to progress further.

Comment: I deleted a previous comment because I realized that the meaning of the sentence is actually this: *Stepan started reading through his letters **while drinking his coffee**.*

Comment: Count the verbs. Every main verb in a sentence represents its own clause. More than one verb = more than one clause. The example sentence has three main verbs: _drinking, started,_ and _reading_. That makes three clauses, so it can't be a simple sentence.

Comment: "Drinking" is a participle, and "reading" is a gerund, so they can't be main verbs.

Comment: No. In traditional "school exam" terms, *drinking his coffee* is a "reduced" clause. But it still functions as a dependent clause to "complexify" the sentence.

Comment: There's nothing reduced about "drinking his coffee". It's simply a non-finite clause. Importantly, it is a supplement and hence **not** a dependent, so it makes no contribution to the simple vs complex contrast.